# Should images be stored in DB or separately?

Tags: asp.net, database-design

I have a web page with a lot of MOV and GIF files, all on form *A0001.MOV* or *A3923.GIF*. Right now, every page I display is named like *A3429.ASPX* and gets its data from a database (it's just a bunch of short texts). One of the fields is a relative link to like */path/dir/A9891* and gets concatenated with an appropriate file ending.

I wonder if it's possible and, if so, wise to move the images and short videos into the database. Never've done it before and I'm not precisely a DB jockey.    :)

Comment: Why do you want to move them to the db? This will involve more cpu usage.

Comment: @nunespascal Portability. Performance is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **SQL Server**, there's a really good paper by Microsoft Research called [To Blob or Not To Blob](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525).

Their conclusion after a large number of performance tests and analysis is this:

- if your pictures or document are typically below 256K in size, storing them in a database `VARBINARY` column is more efficient
- if your pictures or document are typically over 1 MB in size, storing them in the filesystem is more efficient (and with SQL Server 2008's `FILESTREAM` attribute, they're still under transactional control and part of the database)
- in between those two, it's a bit of a toss-up depending on your use

If you decide to put your pictures into a SQL Server table, I would strongly recommend using a separate table for storing those pictures - do not store the employee foto in the employee table - keep them in a separate table. That way, the Employee table can stay lean and mean and very efficient, assuming you don't always need to select the employee foto, too, as part of your queries.

For filegroups, check out [Files and Filegroup Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx) for an intro. Basically, you would either create your database with a separate filegroup for large data structures right from the beginning, or add an additional filegroup later. Let's call it `LARGE_DATA`.

Now, whenever you have a new table to create which needs to store `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARBINARY(MAX)` columns, you can specify this file group for the large data:

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
     (....... define the fields here ......)
     ON Data                   -- the basic "Data" filegroup for the regular data
     TEXTIMAGE_ON LARGE_DATA   -- the filegroup for large chunks of data
```

Check out the MSDN intro on filegroups, and play around with it!

Comment: Oh, this was one nice, quick and informative answer. Should be +2 but SO only allows +1, haha.